# Error while building libxcrypt

Tags: linux, security, selinux, packaging, rpmbuild

I am building the `libxcrypt` package on my [OBS](http://obs-itconsulting.com/obsvm.htm) and I am getting the following error:

```
[   37s] crypt_util.c:268:1: error: type defaults to 'int' in type name [-Werror=implicit-int]
[   37s] crypt_util.c:268:1: error: storage class specified for unnamed parameter
[   37s] crypt_util.c:268:41: error: unknown type name '_ufc_tables_lock'
[   37s] crypt_util.c:251:17: error: 'eperm32tab' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
[   37s] cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
[   37s] make[2]: *** [crypt_util.lo] Error 1
[   37s] make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/libxcrypt-3.0.2/src'
[   37s] make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
[   37s] make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/libxcrypt-3.0.2'
[   37s] make: *** [all] Error 2
[   37s] error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.4ODqAP (%build)
[   37s] 
[   37s] RPM build errors:
[   37s]     Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.4ODqAP (%build)
[   40s] [   29.214031] SysRq : Power Off
[   40s] [   29.215186] reboot: Power down`
```

Comment: Strange, you seems to be the only to get this compilation error... Usually, it means that you have probably misconfigured or messed-up with your system and distribution.

Comment: i am building it on the mer online platform, everything is okay with other packages. i have not configured the  system of late

Comment: I know this is old, but for future readers...

many times newer versions of the compiler are stricter about things that used to be let go with just a warning.  The compile has -Werror, meaning, treat all warnings as errors. You can try to add -Wno-error to your CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS and see if that helps.